# A SQL query cost at least 10s

Tags: sql, oracle

There is a SQL query in my project witch cost 10s+ every time.

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT TP.TOPIC_ID, CK.NAME
    FROM TD_TOPIC TP
    INNER JOIN TD_CIRCLE CK on CK.CIRCLE_ID = TP.CIRCLE_ID AND CK.VALID = 1 AND SYSDATE > CK.EFF_TIME
    WHERE
        TP.VALID = 1 AND TP.FORWARD_FROM_TOPIC_ID = 0
        AND (( TP.TOPIC_TYPE = 1 AND TP.APPROVAL_STATUS = 1) OR TP.TOPIC_TYPE IN (0, 2))
        AND (TP.TOPIC_TYPE != 2 OR EXISTS (
                SELECT 1 FROM TD_VOTE_TOPIC_CONFIG CFG
                WHERE CFG.TOPIC_ID=TP.TOPIC_ID AND SYSDATE > CFG.EFFECT_TIME
        ))
        AND (
            EXISTS (
                    SELECT 1 FROM TD_TOPIC_TAG TG WHERE TG.TOPIC_ID=TP.TOPIC_ID
                    AND TG.TAG_ID IN (1, 2)
            )
            OR EXISTS (
                SELECT 1 FROM TD_CIRCLE_TAG CTG WHERE CTG.CIRCLE_ID=CK.CIRCLE_ID
                    AND CTG.TAG_ID IN (1, 2)
            )
        )
    ORDER BY TP.CREATE_TIME DESC
) WHERE ROWNUM<21
```

[image: ER]

This is the query plan. It takes too many time on `TABLE FULL ACCESS` of `TP_TOPIC`.

```
3   -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
4   | Id  | Operation                        | Name                     | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
5   -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
6   |   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                 |                          |    20 |  4560 |  4286   (1)| 00:00:52 |
7   |*  1 |  COUNT STOPKEY                   |                          |       |       |            |          |
8   |   2 |   VIEW                           |                          | 48986 |    10M|  4286   (1)| 00:00:52 |
9   |*  3 |    SORT ORDER BY STOPKEY         |                          | 48986 |  6936K|  4286   (1)| 00:00:52 |
10  |   4 |     CONCATENATION                |                          |       |       |            |          |
11  |*  5 |      FILTER                      |                          |       |       |            |          |
12  |*  6 |       HASH JOIN                  |                          | 24516 |  3471K|  2140   (1)| 00:00:26 |
13  |*  7 |        TABLE ACCESS FULL         | TD_CIRCLE                |   415 | 44820 |    11   (0)| 00:00:01 |
14  |*  8 |        TABLE ACCESS FULL         | TD_TOPIC                 | 75205 |  2717K|  2128   (1)| 00:00:26 |
15  |*  9 |       TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| TD_CIRCLE_TAG            |     1 |     8 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
16  |* 10 |        INDEX RANGE SCAN          | IDX_TD_CIRCLE_TAG_TAG_ID |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
17  |* 11 |       TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| TD_VOTE_TOPIC_CONFIG     |     1 |    13 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
18  |* 12 |        INDEX RANGE SCAN          | IDX_VTCFG_TOPICID        |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
19  |* 13 |      FILTER                      |                          |       |       |            |          |
20  |* 14 |       HASH JOIN                  |                          | 24516 |  3471K|  2140   (1)| 00:00:26 |
21  |* 15 |        TABLE ACCESS FULL         | TD_CIRCLE                |   415 | 44820 |    11   (0)| 00:00:01 |
22  |* 16 |        TABLE ACCESS FULL         | TD_TOPIC                 | 75205 |  2717K|  2128   (1)| 00:00:26 |
23  |* 17 |       TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| TD_CIRCLE_TAG            |     1 |     8 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
24  |* 18 |        INDEX RANGE SCAN          | IDX_TD_CIRCLE_TAG_TAG_ID |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
25  |* 19 |       TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| TD_TOPIC_TAG             |     1 |     8 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
26  |* 20 |        INDEX RANGE SCAN          | IDX_TD_TOPIC_TAG_TAG_ID  |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
27  |* 21 |       TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| TD_VOTE_TOPIC_CONFIG     |     1 |    13 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
28  |* 22 |        INDEX RANGE SCAN          | IDX_VTCFG_TOPICID        |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
29  -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Table `TD_TOPIC` is very large. And I found `TABLE ACCESS (FULL)` of `TD_TOPIC`. Maybe it is the problem. But I don't know how to make it access by index yet.

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: @Gordon Linoff I want to improve it and make it faster.

Comment: Could you generate an explain plaim in a text format, not a bitmap ? Just prepend your query with `EXPLAIN PLAN FOR your query` --> [explain plan example](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28274/ex_plan.htm#i17492), run this command, then run `SELECT * FROM table(  Dbms_Xplan.display )` which will generate the explain in a text format. Then copy a whole result of th last query and append it to the question.

Comment: My suggestion is to rewrite the query: 1) putting the where conditions in the where clause and not in the join conditions (`CK.VALID = 1 AND SYSDATE > CK.EFF_TIME`); 2) transform the exists to left joins.

Answer (score 1):

```
   SELECT * 
     FROM (
           SELECT TP.TOPIC_ID, 
                  CK.NAME
             FROM TD_TOPIC TP
       INNER JOIN TD_CIRCLE CK 
               ON CK.CIRCLE_ID = TP.CIRCLE_ID 
        LEFT JOIN TD_VOTE_TOPIC_CONFIG CFG
               ON CFG.TOPIC_ID=TP.TOPIC_ID 
        LEFT JOIN TD_CIRCLE_TAG CTG 
               ON CTG.CIRCLE_ID=CK.CIRCLE_ID
            WHERE TP.VALID = 1 
              AND TP.FORWARD_FROM_TOPIC_ID = 0
              AND CK.VALID = 1 
              AND CK.EFF_TIME < SYSDATE
              AND (
                       ( 
                            TP.TOPIC_TYPE = 1 
                        AND TP.APPROVAL_STATUS = 1
                       ) 
                    OR TP.TOPIC_TYPE IN (0, 2)
                  )
              AND (   
                       TP.TOPIC_TYPE != 2 
                    OR
                       CFG.EFFECT_TIME < SYSDATE
                  )
              AND (
                       (
                            TG.TOPIC_ID IS NOT NULL
                        AND TG.TAG_ID IN (1, 2)
                       )
                    OR
                    (
                            CTG.CIRCLE_ID IS NOT NULL
                        AND CTG.TAG_ID IN (1, 2)
                       )        
                  )
         ORDER BY TP.CREATE_TIME DESC
          ) 
    WHERE ROWNUM<21
```